# Remove rows with duplicate combinations of factor levels in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, r-factor

After `bind_rows()` a number of large data.frames, i end up with a data.frame like this:

```
tmp <- data.frame(Query=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A"), target=c("D", "A", "A", "A", "B"), values=runif(5))
tmp
  Query target     values
1     A      D 0.06075322
2     B      A 0.43179750
3     C      A 0.32325309
4     D      A 0.26714620
5     A      B 0.96854999
```

I need to remove all rows which contain combinations of `Query` and `target`, that have appeared before, in either direction (AxD is a duplicate of DxA). In the example, the desired output would be (since row 4 is a duplicate of row 1, and row 5 a duplicate of row 2)

```
tmp
      Query target     values
    1     A      D 0.06075322
    2     B      A 0.43179750
    3     C      A 0.32325309
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` the selected columns and discard `duplicated` rows:

```r
cols = c("Query", "target")
tmp[!duplicated(t(apply(tmp[cols], 1, sort))), ]

#  Query target    values
#1     A      D 0.7205899
#2     B      A 0.5484203
#3     C      A 0.4503456
```

Answer (score 4):

tidyverse

```r
tmp <- data.frame(Query=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A"), target=c("D", "A", "A", "A", "B"), values=runif(5))
tmp
#>   Query target    values
#> 1     A      D 0.4596637
#> 2     B      A 0.1274885
#> 3     C      A 0.2051829
#> 4     D      A 0.4037819
#> 5     A      B 0.1777751

library(tidyverse)

tmp %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fltr = str_c(sort(c_across(c("Query", "target"))), collapse = "")) %>% 
  distinct(fltr, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  select(-fltr) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Query target values
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 A     D       0.460
#> 2 B     A       0.127
#> 3 C     A       0.205
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `vectorized` `pmin/pmax`

```
subset(tmp, !duplicated(cbind(pmin(Query, target), pmax(Query, target))))
  Query target     values
1     A      D 0.06075322
2     B      A 0.43179750
3     C      A 0.32325309
```